# Whatsapp chat export

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to export the chat history from WhatsApp (on Android). The problem is that I live in germany, and that function has been blocked for german users due to legal issues. Are there any alternatives to export the chat history in a readable and searchable format?

Comment: For the time being, using the Whatsapp web client works as an alternative, but it isn't very nice for things like searching for a date.

Comment: you can try [MyPhoneExplorer](https://fjsoft.at/en) it works for sms, maybe it will work for WhatsApp too

Answer (score 0):

**WhatsApp Viewer for PC**

[image]

> - View your WhatsApp chats on PC
> - Have a backup on your computer in case your phone gets lost
> - Conveniently read old conversations without pressing “load older messages”
> - Search messages
> - Export to .txt, .html, .json
> - No need to install Python, SQLite or additional libraries (M2Crypto)
> - All in a small application, no dependencies, no need to install

Source: https://andreas-mausch.de/whatsapp-viewer